# how to get list of images from Instagram Api in flutter

Tags: flutter, instagram-graph-api

when I login Instagram with simple_auth and not getting list of images from Instagram. from
https://graph.instagram.com/me

```
  queryParameters: {
       "fields": "media",
       "access_token": user!.token,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `media` endpoint:

```
GET /me/media?fields={fields}&access_token={access-token}
```

See [Get a User’s Media](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-profiles-and-media/#get-a-user-s-media) for details.

Comment: please send code of get all user images from instagram